# Using parallel on a slurm cluster

Tags: gnu-parallel, opensees

I am looking for a command to parallelize the following command with Gnu Parallel:

```
OpenSees 1.tcl
```

OpenSees is an exe file which is OpenSees.exe in windows and OpenSees in Linux. I want to do parallel processing with parameter study. OpenSees is a seismic analysis tool. 1.tcl is an input file for it.
Please bear in mind that the 1.tcl will go from 1.tcl to 360.tcl and I would like to define the number of processors (In example how many parallel executions will go side by side). In normal conditions there are parallel versions with mpi for OpenSees but this is the sequential version I am asking for.

Comment: OpenSees is the name of an executable file

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. Please click `edit` underneath and try to improve it and add an example and some context. Thank you.

Comment: So, I see you want to run a set of commands in parallel. Please give a list of the first 3 commands and last 2 commands in the list you want to run. Start each line in the list with 4 spaces please.

Comment: OpenSees 1.tcl
    OpenSees 2.tcl
    OpenSees 3.tcl

    OpenSees 359.tcl
    OpenSees 360.tcl

Comment: Are you running this from `bash`?

Comment: I will run it with slurm. So one line is preferred. I will define a job submition file to a cluster with appropriate cpu numbers and cores. The file which is used to submit defines the processor and core numbers so I am not sure about the processor options of parallel.

Comment: You really should add the [tag:slurm] tag!

Comment: I have deleted my answer as I am unsure as to whether you are even running Linux or a slurm cluster or Windows with `bash` or `tcl` or Command Prompt.

Comment: Since before posting to a cluster I am trying at home computer. Cluster is linux (Centos) with slurm. I have the executable for Centos, but I can only install Ubuntu under Windows for trial runs and compilation is very difficult. So I try it this way. #SBATCH -n 24                  # total number of cores
#SBATCH -N 1                   # total number of machines (These are the slurm entries for core and machine numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This is the slurm sh script I used, but it only worked for one machine, I could not add more than one machine, so I build more shell scripts with numbers >28 to 360. These are the necessary parts of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 28                  # total number of cores
#SBATCH -N 1                   # machine number

parallel --bar ./OpenSees {}.tcl ::: {1..28}
```

Comment: parallel --bar ./OpenSees {}.tcl ::: {1..28} is the answer deleted whose details can be found on comments of question.